# Does collect operation on Stream close the stream and underlying resources?

Tags: java, file-io, java-8, java-stream, try-with-resources

Does below code need to be wrapped in try-with-resources to make sure underlying file is closed?

```
List<String> rows = Files.lines(inputFilePath).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The design of Stream and close() was very controversial. To be safe, always close a Stream if you are unsure. And even that may not be enough, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20319417/why-is-bufferedreader-not-closed-when-obtaining-streamstring-in-try-with-res

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the javadoc of the overloaded [`Files#lines(Path, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) method states

> The returned stream encapsulates a `Reader`. If timely disposal of file
>   system resources is required, the `try-with-resources` construct should
>   be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the
>   stream operations are completed.

So yes, wrap the `Stream` returned by `lines` in a `try-with-resources` statement. (Or [close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#close--) it appropriately.)

Answer (score 35):

There is a trick to make the `Stream` implementation calling `close()` after the terminal operation:

```
List<String> rows = Stream.of(Files.lines(inputFilePath)).flatMap(s->s)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It simply creates a stream encapsulating the stream of lines as a single item and uses `flatMap` with an identity function (`Function.identity()` would work as well) to turn it into a stream of lines again.

The interesting point is a [property of `Stream.flatMap(…)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

> Each mapped stream is closed after its contents have been placed into this stream.

So the code above will close the stream of lines. While it looks more concise it has the disadvantage over try with resources that current implementation of `flatMap` [lacks lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29229373/2711488) which is not relevant here as you are collecting all lines into a list anyway. But it’s something to keep in mind when using this trick in other scenarios.

---

For the question’s code as-is there is an even simpler solution:

```
List<String> rows = Files.readAllLines(inputFilePath);
```

Reads all lines and closes all resources…

Comment: I tried your solution, and it works. I also assumed that it would be equivalent to `Files.lines(inputFilePath).flatMap(Stream::of)` but to my surprise it was not. The latter did not actually close the stream. (on jdk1.8.0_221)

Comment: @neXus `.flatMap(Stream::of)` creates a new single element stream for each element and flattens them back to an equivalent stream as before the flatMap. Those single element streams will be closed, but that has no effect.